# How to get the CPU utilization for Java8 in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Google AppEngine application written in Java using JDK8.

I want to get the CPU utilization. How can I achieve that?

I have tried two approaches:

1. ```
   final OperatingSystemMXBean os = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(); // this is the java.lang version
   final double systemCpuLoadRatio = Math.max(0.0, os.getSystemLoadAverage() / os.getAvailableProcessors());
   final long systemCpuLoad = (long) (systemCpuLoadRatio * 100);
   ```
2. ```
   OperatingSystemMXBean os = (OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() // This is the sun.management version.
   final long systemCpuLoad = os.getAvailableProcessors();
   ```

Both approaches always yield zero as the result. The CPU utilization cannot be 0 as there are real requests ongoing.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to check this information in your code? You can check the App Engine CPU utilization on the dashboard, and set [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#apps_with_automatic_scaling) depending on the CPU utilization.

Comment: The first call when instantiating the MXBean is often 0 because it doesn't have time to measure an interval.  Try calling it 1 second later.   Also, avoid using option 2 as it ties you to the Oracle MXBean (and thus you can't use it in production without license fees).

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying by 100.0 then let the cast remove the fractional part...

You may also try the oshi framework: https://github.com/oshi